# Convert function into a global function

Tags: ios, objective-c, function

Could someone please help me convert this into a global function? I will be using this code in multiple places, so it does not make sense to copy and paste it multiple times.

I'd like to be able to call `abbreviateNumber(number)` and have it run through the function.

```
-(NSString *)abbreviateNumber:(int)num {

    NSString *abbrevNum;
    float number = (float)num;

    if (num >= 1000) {
        NSArray *abbrev = @[@"k", @"m", @"b"];

        for (int i = abbrev.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            int size = pow(10,(i+1)*3);

            if(size <= number) {
                number = number/size;
                NSString *numberString = [self floatToString:number];

                abbrevNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", numberString, [abbrev objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
    } else {
        abbrevNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)number];
    }

    return abbrevNum;
}

- (NSString *) floatToString:(float) val {
    NSString *ret = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", val];
    unichar c = [ret characterAtIndex:[ret length] - 1];

    while (c == 48) {
        ret = [ret substringToIndex:[ret length] - 1];
        c = [ret characterAtIndex:[ret length] - 1];

        if(c == 46) {
            ret = [ret substringToIndex:[ret length] - 1];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**EDIT:**

For example, I have a global function like this, but I do not know how to put the above in that type of format:

```
void showServerError() {
    [[TWMessageBarManager sharedInstance] showMessageWithTitle:@"Server Error"
    description:SERVER_ERROR
    type:TWMessageBarMessageTypeError
    duration:4.0];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the two functions as categories on `NSString`, and call them from there:

```
@interface NSString(MyNSStringCategoryName)
+ (NSString *)stringByAbbreviatingNumber:(int)num;
+ (NSString *)stringFromFloat:(float)val;
@end
```

in a `NSString+MyNSStringCategoryName.h` file, and

```
@implementation NSString(MyNSStringCategoryName)
+ (NSString *)stringByAbbreviatingNumber:(int)num {
    // ... your code
}

+ (NSString *)stringFromFloat:(float)val {
  // ... your code
}
@end
```

in a `NSString+MyNSStringCategoryName.m`.

You can then call those class methods like this:

```
abbrevString = [NSString stringByAbbreviatingNumber:someNumber];
floatString = [NSString stringFromFloat:someFloat];
```

You gain modularization like this as you keep the string methods grouped together, while also having the benefit of having them globally available.

Answer (score 1):

Cristik's answer is good, but if you have a variety of tools you can make a class, for example, myGlobalTools and declare your methods as class methods. Change the - to a plus in the method declaration;

```
        +(NSString *)abbreviateNumber:(int)num;
```

you can call them with;

```
    [myGlobalTools abbreviateNumber:aNum];
```